# Released .NET Program Crashing

Tags: c#, exception, crash

I have a .NET application that I finished and is running on a customer machine.  Im getting reports that it will occasionally crash with a windows error box

xxxProgram has stopped working, A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

I am trying to track the source of this problem.  I figure it is an unhandled exception somewhere but I am having trouble finding where.  Im looking for input on help to track the source.  Although the program is .NET I am using some unmanaged resources like OPC and a small wrapper I wrote but I feel like I covered the marshalling well.  The application runs almost 24/7 and currently it crashes maybe once every 4-10 days.

One thing I was thinking about was subscribing to the `AppDomain.UnhandledExceptionEventHandler` and logging a stack trace to a file.  Is this possible and how would one go about doing it??

Thanks

Comment: Not a programmatic solution, but a comment from a fellow troubleshooter -- Much of the time, with apps that terminate unexpectedly, there is something relevant logged in the Windows event viewer, like the particular stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a logging system. Even if its just a try catch to get basic errors from a page. I have used the code below before to store a log file on the server.

```
public void logError(string errorString)
{
     try
     {
         // Takes unknown errors and logs them to the log file 
         string user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
         string FileLine = user + ", " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ", " + errorString;
         string filename = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../Log/error_log.txt");

         using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, true))
         {
             file.WriteLine(FileLine);
             file.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        // send email, or another notification 
     }

}
```

You can call it like:

```
try
{
   //function code
}
catch (Exception ex)
{                                                                                
   logError(ex.ToString());
}
```